# What if the Fragment throw an Exception?

Tags: android, android-fragments, exception

What if I have a method inside a `Fragment` (perhaps a `ListFragment`) that throws an exception (perhaps an `IOException`).

Should the Fragment by itself call a inline `DialogFragment` of its own that alerts the user of the exception?

Or should the Fragment call a callback method declared in an inline `Interface` implemented by the hosting `Activity` and let the Activity deal with the exception however it feels fit?

Comment: `Fragment`s don't throw exceptions, methods do.

Comment: Matter of taste I guess. I tend to lean towards the last option, as it in my case prevents some code redundancy.

Comment: @Rajesh, duh obviously. I rephrased the question for clarity.

Comment: @cYrixmorten, I see. The Fragment training documentation states it should be a "completely self-contained, modular component". Calling external callbacks lead to more code required re-use the Fragment though. There must be some balance between callbacks, because else everything in a Fragment could be a callback, and then things have probably gone too far.

Comment: Sounds to make sense. Though, as the fragment by nature is tightly coupled to it'a activity, I see no problem in having code required by multiple fragments reside in the activity. If the Exception is unique for that fragment and not generic, surely it would not be nice to have outside code handle the dialog creation etc.

Answer (score 1):

Surely this is an architectural decision that you must make yourself? I wouldn't have said there's a right and wrong way of doing it (but I was wrong once before!)